# How to position HTML code over CSS

Tags: html, css

In my website I want to be able to put the two text boxes (in the top left hand corner) over the other boxes made from CSS. But because I'm not that good yet I am not sure what to do. Please could you help me?

Visit here to see what I mean - http://jsfiddle.net/xiiJaMiiE/RGp5x/

```
<h1>
    <input type="text" name="textbox1" size="20" height="50"/>
    </br>
    <input type="text" name="textbox2" size="20" height="50"/>
</h1>
```

Also if possible, is there a way to change the text box from white to dark grey?

Comment: What do you mean by "the other boxes made from CSS"?

Comment: Why did someone downvote this?  It's actually a properly-asked question with a clear goal and code example for what was tried.

Comment: Do you want the textboxes to be above everything?

Comment: @MohamedKhamis The white box with the border, and the title bar is all made by CSS

Comment: @Deryck thank you, its stupid why some people do that!

Comment: @Dozer789 yes please, the two little text boxes in the top left corner, I would like them to be above everything, so i can see them

Comment: @xiiJaMiiE You already got an answer... Looks like you don't need mine. :)

Comment: Haha, just a bit quicker ;), thanks anyway! @Dozer789

Comment: @xiiJaMiiE No problem! Hopefully I can help you sometime later!

Comment: @Dozer789 You most probably will, I'm a noob haha is there a way to contact you? I need some help again haha?

Comment: @xiiJaMiiE We were all noobs at one time. I just started learning web programming a few weeks ago, and thanks to stackoverflow, I have fixed a lot of my problems! It is a great community here, and there are a lot of users, so you should get an answer to your questions!

Comment: Ahh I suppose, i agree this site is amazing for answers! so many good and nice people. Do you know how i can make the white text box bigger in height? I can't seem to do it. @Dozer789

Comment: @xiiJaMiiE If you have another question, post another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your `<input>` tags in their own `<div>` like this:

```
<div id=signin>    
<input type="text" name="textbox1" size="20" height="50"/></br>
<input type="text" name="textbox2" size="20" height="50"/>
    </div>
```

Then add this CSS to your stylesheet:

```
#signin {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:100;
    background-color:lightgrey;
    border: 1px solid grey;

}
#signin input {
 background-color:green;   
}
```

You can tweak the details yourself. I've updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RGp5x/2/)

Answer (score 1):

two important things:
1st you should clean your code, guess you copied/pasted something, there are more than one and mixed head / body / html TAGs.

clean it should look like

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

After you corrected this it will be much easier. Just put all the css code in the `head` section, your input fields are inside the `body` area anyway, so you can get them styled same as all other elements.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <style> css </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      html-elements
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I haven't copied and pasted anything :S I have wrote this near enough all my self. (apart from a little help from amazing people on here) But i will still tidy it up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To push the white div behind the text box, add to its CSS style the following: `z-index=-10`

As for changing the text box's color, use the `background-color` like this:

```
<input type='text' style='background-color:#696969'/>
```

Comment: This won't help because the elements are positioned absolutely which over-rides z-index for static or relative elements.